# Javascript function does not display alert box

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a javascript project I am working on that take information and submits it. I am supposed to validate that the quantity inputs only have numbers in them and pop up an alert box and not submit if they do not. They can be blank as long as if they have anything input it is only numbers. I have validated it, and looked at the submission page and it shows that if I put in letters the particular quantity field does not submit (I have three quantities), but everything else does. It is supposed to throw up an alert and stop the page from submitting if any of the quantities are not numbers. I have looked at this over and over and tried a few things, but cannot seem to find my error. I would appreciate any direction on where to look to correct this.

```
<script>
  //function to check for valid fruit quantities
  function certifyDigits() {
    var b = document.getElementById("blueberries").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("cherries").value;
    var s = document.getElementbyId("strawberries").value;
    if (!b.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      alert("Please enter only numbers for quantity!");
      return false;
    }

    if (!c.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      alert("Please enter only numbers for quantity!");
      return false;
    }

    if (!s.match(/^\d+$/)) {
      alert("Please enter only numbers for quantity!");
      return false;
    }

  }
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Fruit Purchasing Form</h2>

  <table class="main">
    <tr>
      <th class="a">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="a">Blueberries</th>
      <th class="a">Cherries</th>
      <th class="a">Strawberries</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="a">Price</th>
      <td class="b">$2.50</td>
      <td class="b">$4.40</td>
      <td class="b">$8.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="a">Shipping Weight</th>
      <td class="b">2.0</td>
      <td class="b">4.0</td>
      <td class="b">4.0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />

  <form name="fruitOrder" action="http://www.textXXX.php" method="post" onSubmit="return certifyDigits()">

    <h3>Select Quantity of Fruit Desired</h3>
    <br />

    <p>Blueberries:</p>
    <input id="blueberries" type="text" size=5>
    <p>Cherries:</p>
    <input id="cherries" type="text" size=5>
    <p>Strawberries:</p>
    <input id="strawberries" type="text" size=5>

    <br />
    <br />

    <h3>Customer Information</h3>
    <br />
    <label>Your Last Name:
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" size="25" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>Your First Name:
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" size="25" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>Street Address:
      <input type="text" name="street" id="street" size="60" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>City, State, Zip Code:
      <input type="text" name="citystatezip" id="citystatezip" size="60" />
    </label>
    <br />

    <h3>Payment Method</h3>
    <label>Visa
      <input type="radio" name="payment_type" id="payment_type_Visa" value="Visa" checked />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>Mastercard
      <input type="radio" name="payment_type" id="payment_type_MC" value="MC" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>American_Express
      <input type="radio" name="payment_type" id="payment_type_amex" value="amex" />
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript match() function always returns an array.  If the match is true, then the array will contain the matching value.  If the match is false, then the array will contain an empty string.  Change your if statements to

```
if (b.match(/^\d+$/)[0] === "") {
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not validate the input for numbers only?

```
function validate_numbers(evt){ 
  var theEvent=evt || window.event; 
  var key=theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which; 
  key=String.fromCharCode(key); 
  var regex=/[0-9]|\.|\,|\/|\ /;

  if(!regex.test(key)){ 
    theEvent.returnValue=false; 
    if(theEvent.preventDefault)theEvent.preventDefault(); 
  }; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be: document.getElementById("strawberries").value;

Not: document.getElementbyId("strawberries").value;

You are using small letter b for getElementById which causes an error. 
To easily see errors like this, enable preserve log on chrome. On my end the error is: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function

To prevent the page from sending on error add return false; in function certifyDigits(). You can also set variables that will store number of errors, if there is an error, return false.

See below.

```
function certifyDigits(){
    var fruits = ["blueberries", "cherries", "strawberries"];
    var errors_count = 0;

    for(var ctr = 0; ctr < fruits.length; ctr ++){
        if(! document.getElementById(fruits[ctr]).value.match(/^\d+$/)){
            errors_count++;
        }
    }

    if(errors_count > 0){
        alert("Please enter only numbers for quantity!");
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By the context, you were using match instead of test.
To make everything works correctly, use `/^\d+$/.test(b)` this will return True or False, and you may want to alert once if either of them input is incorrect (instead of three alerts), to do this include `||` in the if statement which stands for or, Cheers !